# Compare 2 excel sheets and find values not in sheet 2

Tags: excel, compare

I have 2 sheets in a excel file, sheet one has 287 rows and in sheet 2 there is 123 rows. The columns are the same in both sheets. How can I compare and see which rows in sheet 1 is not present in sheet 2?

Comment: Must all cells in a row match for it to be considered a duplicate, or do you only look at each cell individually?

Comment: No, only one should be enough

Comment: Assuming the 1st cell of the 123 rows is A1, put `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1)` in B1 and drag downwards.